# Removing points not within Polygon doesn't remove all points

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

This is how I remove nodes that are outside a bounding box:

```
db.nodes.remove({
    "coordinates": {
        "$exists": True,
        "$not": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [[9.675, 53.375], [9.675, 53.75], [10.425, 53.75], [10.425, 53.375], [9.675, 53.375]]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But after that operation, where a lot of points are removed, I still have these:

```
{'type': 'Point', '_id': 27334421, 'coordinates': [10.2449721, 53.7503602]}
{'type': 'Point', '_id': 257404368, 'coordinates': [10.1338037, 53.7500432]}
{'type': 'Point', '_id': 1247259233, 'coordinates': [10.0893782, 53.7501643]}
{'type': 'Point', '_id': 1650544564, 'coordinates': [10.244542, 53.7500947]}
```

Am I doing something wrong, getting something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: You have a bounding line rather than a box (the 53.375s). Should it be a line? If so, then there are easy ways for testing if a point is on a line as well as how close it is to that line? The points are within rounding error of being on that line. You can certainly get more precise, but you might want to ask yourself if it's really required. If it's not supposed to be a line, you should fix that first and see if it's still an issue.

Comment: Why is this not a polygon?

Comment: Actually, they do form a box, got careless and missed a digit as I skimmed over the coordinates. Or rather I had it right, then amusingly seemed to have somehow managed to erroneously convince myself of being wrong first by thinking it was a triangle then a line. It's still valid that they they lie very close to a line that makes up the edge of that bounding box though. Just ignore the first two sentences and last sentence of that comment. The points are very close to being on the line segment formed by `[ [9.675, 53.75] ,[10.425, 53.75] ]`.

Comment: When I cut that large polygon into 25 equal sized pieces and use the query without the $not for each of those, no polygon contains these four points! Nevertheless I just changed how I retrieve data from openstreetmap.

Comment: Interesting, as long as you got it to work in the end.